# Can I do this with a single SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay, I have a single table like this:

```
id  query  results  ip
---------------------------------
1   milk   17       10.10.10.1
2   milk   17       10.10.10.1
3   milk   17       10.10.10.2
4   bread  8        10.10.10.2
5   bread  8        10.10.10.2
6   cheese 12       10.10.10.1
```

I have this query right now:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as cnt, query, results, ip
FROM table
GROUP BY query
ORDER BY results ASC
LIMIT 20
```

This query returns these results:

```
count  query  results
---------------------
2      bread  8
1      cheese 12
3      milk   17
```

I need to expand on that query (or redo it completely) to return something like this, preferably with the IP's in a nested array as part of the query's array:

```
query  count  results  ip
--------------------------------
bread  2      8        10.10.10.2 (2)
cheese 1      12       10.10.10.1 (1)
milk   3      17       10.10.10.1 (2)
                       10.10.10.2 (1)
```

I'll be outputting this with php, attaching the IP list with that count to the query count display (click to show/hide a modal with the info populated).

Any direction or help to get the data I need out would be wonderful!

Comment: You mean `DISTINCT` right ?   :-)

Comment: The desired result set violates 1NF. You may want to think of a better way of querying that.

Comment: Probably [SQL join to itself](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/join-a-table-to-itself.php)?

Comment: @LucM - er, yes - fixed.  Kendall - the result set isn't a table, so I don't think 1NF applies.  Correct me if I'm wrong, though - it happens more than I'd like to admit.

Comment: See the existing answers with multiple group by columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this (despite numerous claims to the contrary) is "Yes you can, with a derived table":

```
SELECT
  SUM(cnt) as cnt,
  query, results,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ip SEPARATOR '\n') AS ip
FROM (
  SELECT
    query, results,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as cnt,
    CONCAT(ip, '(', COUNT(ip), ')') AS ip
  FROM test
  GROUP BY query, ip
) t
GROUP BY query
ORDER BY results ASC
LIMIT 20
```

[Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c2b3/25)...

The one thing you *cannot* do is have PHP understand that the value of `ip` is an array with no other interference. However, you could do [this slightly nasty thing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c2b3/27) to dynamically construct the data into JSON, and then it can simply be passed to `json_decode()` in PHP to easily convert it to a PHP vector type.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't get that result. You have two options:

1. Get each IP address on its own row and loop intelligently through the results in PHP.
2. Use the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) MySQL function to concatenate the IP addresses together in one field and parse the field to separate them in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be a nested array, but you could have something like

```
SELECT query, results, ip, COUNT(ip) AS cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY query, ip
ORDER BY results ASC
LIMIT 20
```

where you group on query AND ip

Comment: [Sass *me* for the hoopy frood *I* am](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c2b3/26)... I know you really don't care but I just had to show off to someone who's opinion I actually respect :-D

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be what you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as cnt, query, results, ip
FROM table
GROUP BY query, ip
ORDER BY results ASC
LIMIT 20
```

This would give you a result like this:

```
query   count  results  ip
----------------------------------
bread   2      8        10.10.10.2
cheese  1      12       10.10.10.1
milk    2      17       10.10.10.1
milk    1      17       10.10.10.2
```

Unfortunately, you can't use a nested array, but this is fairly close.

Answer (score 2):

[group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will work well for this. But remember to use distinct(ip) inside group_concat().

The following is a working query from mysql which I tried.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as cnt, query, results, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ip)) 
FROM table
GROUP BY query 
ORDER BY results ASC LIMIT 20;

+-----+--------+---------+----------------------------+
| cnt | query  | results | group_concat(distinct(ip)) |
+-----+--------+---------+----------------------------+
|   2 | bread  |       8 | 10.10.10.2                 |
|   1 | cheese |      12 | 10.10.10.1                 |
|   3 | milk   |      17 | 10.10.10.1,10.10.10.2      |
+-----+--------+---------+----------------------------+
```

When I run the query without distinct(ip) inside group_concat:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as cnt, query, results, group_concat(ip) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY query 
ORDER BY results ASC LIMIT 20;

+-----+--------+---------+----------------------------------+
| cnt | query  | results | group_concat(ip)                 |
+-----+--------+---------+----------------------------------+
|   2 | bread  |       8 | 10.10.10.2,10.10.10.2            |
|   1 | cheese |      12 | 10.10.10.1                       |
|   3 | milk   |      17 | 10.10.10.1,10.10.10.1,10.10.10.2 |
+-----+--------+---------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: You don't *need* the `DISTINCT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as cnt, query, results, GROUP_CONCAT(ip) AS ip
FROM table
GROUP BY query
ORDER BY results ASC
LIMIT 20
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` will combine the `ip` fields into a comma separated string.